# How to make radiobutton selected one at time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, gridview

I have the below code to display information into gridview and enable user to select choice, but I want user to select only one choice not multiple choices.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:RadioButton ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" GroupName="select"/>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**So how can I allow user to check only one RadioButton?**

Comment: Do you mean in all rows only one radiobutton can be selected (and not in each row)?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Use a RadioButtonList

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList id="Rdlist" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The control is well documented on [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use simple input type = radio and make sure name should be same for all radio where you want only one to be selected

```
<input type="radio" ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  name="somename" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a GroupName to each radio button in the grid.

See definition -> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)